ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: This connection is in use by: #<Fiber:0x0000000XXXX (resumed)>
I see this error randomly when I run the rails test.
After I upgraded some of my gems.
I have been activating and deactivating them one by one. The new ones prometheus_client and amazing_print don't look like they are causing the error.
I am sure it is something to do with the concurrency and multithreading of the rails test but I don't know.
These are the changes in my Gemfile.lock:
diff --git a/Gemfile.lock b/Gemfile.lock
index 3a6053d..9070d04 100644
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -9,193 +9,173 @@ GIT
 GEM
   remote: https://rubygems.org/
   specs:
-    actioncable (7.0.2.2)
-      actionpack (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
+    actioncable (7.1.3.2)
+      actionpack (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
       nio4r (~> 2.0)
       websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
-    actionmailbox (7.0.2.2)
-      actionpack (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activejob (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activerecord (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activestorage (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
+      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
+    actionmailbox (7.1.3.2)
+      actionpack (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activejob (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activerecord (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activestorage (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
       mail (>= 2.7.1)
       net-imap
       net-pop
       net-smtp
-    actionmailer (7.0.2.2)
-      actionpack (= 7.0.2.2)
-      actionview (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activejob (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
+    actionmailer (7.1.3.2)
+      actionpack (= 7.1.3.2)
+      actionview (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activejob (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
       mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
       net-imap
       net-pop
       net-smtp
-      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
-    actionpack (7.0.2.2)
-      actionview (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
-      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.2.0)
+      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.2)
+    actionpack (7.1.3.2)
+      actionview (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
+      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
+      racc
+      rack (>= 2.2.4)
+      rack-session (>= 1.0.1)
       rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
-      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
-      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
-    actiontext (7.0.2.2)
-      actionpack (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activerecord (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activestorage (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
+      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.2)
+      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.6)
+    actiontext (7.1.3.2)
+      actionpack (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activerecord (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activestorage (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
       globalid (>= 0.6.0)
       nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
-    actionview (7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
+    actionview (7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
       builder (~> 3.1)
-      erubi (~> 1.4)
-      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
-      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
-    active_storage_validations (0.9.7)
+      erubi (~> 1.11)
+      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.2)
+      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.6)
+    active_storage_validations (1.1.4)
       activejob (>= 5.2.0)
       activemodel (>= 5.2.0)
       activestorage (>= 5.2.0)
       activesupport (>= 5.2.0)
-    activejob (7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
+    activejob (7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
       globalid (>= 0.3.6)
-    activemodel (7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
-    activerecord (7.0.2.2)
-      activemodel (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
-    activestorage (7.0.2.2)
-      actionpack (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activejob (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activerecord (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
+    activemodel (7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
+    activerecord (7.1.3.2)
+      activemodel (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
+      timeout (>= 0.4.0)
+    activestorage (7.1.3.2)
+      actionpack (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activejob (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activerecord (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
       marcel (~> 1.0)
-      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
-    activesupport (7.0.2.2)
+    activesupport (7.1.3.2)
+      base64
+      bigdecimal
       concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
+      connection_pool (>= 2.2.5)
+      drb
       i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
       minitest (>= 5.1)
+      mutex_m
       tzinfo (~> 2.0)
-    acts-as-taggable-on (9.0.1)
-      activerecord (>= 6.0, < 7.1)
-    addressable (2.8.0)
-      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
+    acts-as-taggable-on (10.0.0)
+      activerecord (>= 6.1, < 7.2)
+    amazing_print (1.6.0)
     ast (2.4.2)
-    authlogic (6.4.2)
-      activemodel (>= 5.2, < 7.1)
-      activerecord (>= 5.2, < 7.1)
-      activesupport (>= 5.2, < 7.1)
+    authlogic (6.4.3)
+      activemodel (>= 5.2, < 7.2)
+      activerecord (>= 5.2, < 7.2)
+      activesupport (>= 5.2, < 7.2)
       request_store (~> 1.0)
-    awesome_print (1.9.2)
-    aws-eventstream (1.2.0)
-    aws-partitions (1.563.0)
-    aws-sdk-core (3.128.1)
-      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
-      aws-partitions (~> 1, >= 1.525.0)
+    aws-eventstream (1.3.0)
+    aws-partitions (1.927.0)
+    aws-sdk-core (3.195.0)
+      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.3.0)
+      aws-partitions (~> 1, >= 1.651.0)
+      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.8)
+      jmespath (~> 1, >= 1.6.1)
+    aws-sdk-kms (1.80.0)
+      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.193.0)
       aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
-      jmespath (~> 1.0)
-    aws-sdk-kms (1.55.0)
-      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.127.0)
-      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
-    aws-sdk-s3 (1.113.0)
-      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.127.0)
+    aws-sdk-s3 (1.149.1)
+      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.194.0)
       aws-sdk-kms (~> 1)
-      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.4)
-    aws-sigv4 (1.4.0)
+      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.8)
+    aws-sigv4 (1.8.0)
       aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
     axiom-types (0.1.1)
       descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.4)
       ice_nine (~> 0.11.0)
       thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
     base64 (0.2.0)
+    bigdecimal (3.1.8)
     bindex (0.8.1)
     bluecloth (2.2.0)
-    brakeman (5.2.1)
+    brakeman (6.1.2)
+      racc
     builder (3.2.4)
     bundle-audit (0.1.0)
       bundler-audit
-    bundler-audit (0.9.0.1)
+    bundler-audit (0.9.1)
       bundler (>= 1.2.0, < 3)
       thor (~> 1.0)
     byebug (11.1.3)
-    capybara (3.36.0)
-      addressable
-      matrix
-      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
-      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
-      rack (>= 1.6.0)
-      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
-      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
-      xpath (~> 3.2)
-    childprocess (4.1.0)
-    coderay (1.1.3)
     coercible (1.0.0)
       descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
-    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
+    concurrent-ruby (1.2.3)
+    connection_pool (2.4.1)
     crass (1.0.6)
-    data_migrate (8.0.0)
-      activerecord (>= 5.0)
-      railties (>= 5.0)
-    database_cleaner (2.0.1)
-      database_cleaner-active_record (~> 2.0.0)
-    database_cleaner-active_record (2.0.1)
-      activerecord (>= 5.a)
-      database_cleaner-core (~> 2.0.0)
-    database_cleaner-core (2.0.1)
+    data_migrate (9.4.0)
+      activerecord (>= 6.1)
+      railties (>= 6.1)
+    date (3.3.4)
     descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
       thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
-    digest (3.1.0)
     docile (1.4.0)
-    dotenv (2.7.6)
-    dotenv-rails (2.7.6)
-      dotenv (= 2.7.6)
-      railties (>= 3.2)
+    dotenv (3.1.2)
+    dotenv-rails (3.1.2)
+      dotenv (= 3.1.2)
+      railties (>= 6.1)
+    drb (2.2.1)
     equalizer (0.0.11)
-    erubi (1.10.0)
-    execjs (2.8.1)
-    factory_bot (6.2.0)
+    erubi (1.12.0)
+    execjs (2.9.1)
+    factory_bot (6.4.6)
       activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
-    faker (2.20.0)
+    faker (3.3.1)
       i18n (>= 1.8.11, < 2)
     faraday (2.9.0)
       faraday-net_http (>= 2.0, < 3.2)
     faraday-net_http (3.1.0)
       net-http
     fast_blank (1.0.1)
-    ffi (1.15.5)
-    ffi-compiler (1.0.1)
-      ffi (>= 1.0.0)
+    ffi (1.16.3)
+    ffi-compiler (1.3.2)
+      ffi (>= 1.15.5)
       rake
-    formatador (1.1.0)
-    globalid (1.0.0)
-      activesupport (>= 5.0)
-    guard (2.18.0)
-      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
-      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
-      lumberjack (>= 1.0.12, < 2.0)
-      nenv (~> 0.1)
-      notiffany (~> 0.0)
-      pry (>= 0.13.0)
-      shellany (~> 0.0)
-      thor (>= 0.18.1)
-    guard-compat (1.2.1)
-    guard-minitest (2.4.6)
-      guard-compat (~> 1.2)
-      minitest (>= 3.0)
+    globalid (1.2.1)
+      activesupport (>= 6.1)
     hashie (5.0.0)
-    highline (2.0.3)
-    i18n (1.10.0)
+    highline (3.0.1)
+    i18n (1.14.5)
       concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
-    i18n-tasks (0.9.37)
+    i18n-tasks (1.0.14)
       activesupport (>= 4.0.2)
       ast (>= 2.1.0)
       erubi
       highline (>= 2.0.0)
       i18n
-      parser (>= 2.2.3.0)
+      parser (>= 3.2.2.1)
       rails-i18n
       rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
       terminal-table (>= 1.5.1)
@@ -203,12 +183,15 @@ GEM
     image_processing (1.12.2)
       mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
       ruby-vips (>= 2.0.17, < 3)
-    io-wait (0.2.1)
-    jbuilder (2.11.5)
+    io-console (0.7.2)
+    irb (1.13.1)
+      rdoc (>= 4.0.0)
+      reline (>= 0.4.2)
+    jbuilder (2.12.0)
       actionview (>= 5.0.0)
       activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
-    jmespath (1.6.1)
-    jquery-rails (4.4.0)
+    jmespath (1.6.2)
+    jquery-rails (4.6.0)
       rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
       railties (>= 4.2.0)
       thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
@@ -226,55 +209,44 @@ GEM
       activerecord
       kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
     kaminari-core (1.2.2)
-    listen (3.7.1)
-      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
-      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
-    log_book (0.7.1)
+    log_book (0.9.1)
       acts-as-taggable-on (>= 8.0)
       rails (>= 6.0)
-    loofah (2.14.0)
+    loofah (2.22.0)
       crass (~> 1.0.2)
-      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
-    lumberjack (1.2.8)
+      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
     macaddr (1.7.2)
       systemu (~> 2.6.5)
-    mail (2.7.1)
+    mail (2.8.1)
       mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
-    marcel (1.0.2)
-    matrix (0.4.2)
-    method_source (1.0.0)
-    mini_magick (4.11.0)
-    mini_mime (1.1.2)
-    mini_portile2 (2.8.0)
-    minitest (5.15.0)
-    mocha (1.13.0)
+      net-imap
+      net-pop
+      net-smtp
+    marcel (1.0.4)
+    mini_magick (4.12.0)
+    mini_mime (1.1.5)
+    mini_portile2 (2.8.6)
+    minitest (5.22.3)
+    mocha (2.2.0)
+      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.5)
     multi_xml (0.6.0)
+    mutex_m (0.2.0)
     mysql2 (0.5.6)
-    nenv (0.3.0)
     net-http (0.4.1)
       uri
-    net-imap (0.2.3)
-      digest
+    net-imap (0.4.11)
+      date
       net-protocol
-      strscan
-    net-pop (0.1.1)
-      digest
+    net-pop (0.1.2)
       net-protocol
+    net-protocol (0.2.2)
       timeout
-    net-protocol (0.1.2)
-      io-wait
-      timeout
-    net-smtp (0.3.1)
-      digest
+    net-smtp (0.5.0)
       net-protocol
-      timeout
-    nio4r (2.5.8)
-    nokogiri (1.13.3)
-      mini_portile2 (~> 2.8.0)
+    nio4r (2.7.3)
+    nokogiri (1.16.4)
+      mini_portile2 (~> 2.8.2)
       racc (~> 1.4)
-    notiffany (0.1.3)
-      nenv (~> 0.1)
-      shellany (~> 0.0)
     oauth2 (2.0.9)
       faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 3.0)
       jwt (>= 1.0, < 3.0)
@@ -282,7 +254,8 @@ GEM
       rack (>= 1.2, < 4)
       snaky_hash (~> 2.0)
       version_gem (~> 1.1)
-    oj (3.13.11)
+    oj (3.16.3)
+      bigdecimal (>= 3.0)
     omniauth (2.1.2)
       hashie (>= 3.4.6)
       rack (>= 2.2.3)
@@ -295,73 +268,81 @@ GEM
     omniauth-oauth2 (1.8.0)
       oauth2 (>= 1.4, < 3)
       omniauth (~> 2.0)
-    omniauth-rails_csrf_protection (1.0.1)
+    omniauth-rails_csrf_protection (1.0.2)
       actionpack (>= 4.2)
       omniauth (~> 2.0)
-    parser (3.1.1.0)
+    parser (3.3.1.0)
       ast (~> 2.4.1)
-    power_assert (2.0.1)
-    pry (0.14.1)
-      coderay (~> 1.1)
-      method_source (~> 1.0)
-    public_suffix (4.0.6)
-    puma (5.6.2)
+      racc
+    power_assert (2.0.3)
+    prometheus-client (4.2.2)
+    psych (5.1.2)
+      stringio
+    puma (6.4.2)
       nio4r (~> 2.0)
-    racc (1.6.0)
-    rack (2.2.9)
-    rack-protection (3.2.0)
+    racc (1.7.3)
+    rack (3.0.11)
+    rack-protection (4.0.0)
       base64 (>= 0.1.0)
-      rack (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.4)
-    rack-test (1.1.0)
-      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
-    rails (7.0.2.2)
-      actioncable (= 7.0.2.2)
-      actionmailbox (= 7.0.2.2)
-      actionmailer (= 7.0.2.2)
-      actionpack (= 7.0.2.2)
-      actiontext (= 7.0.2.2)
-      actionview (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activejob (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activemodel (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activerecord (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activestorage (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
+      rack (>= 3.0.0, < 4)
+    rack-session (2.0.0)
+      rack (>= 3.0.0)
+    rack-test (2.1.0)
+      rack (>= 1.3)
+    rackup (2.1.0)
+      rack (>= 3)
+      webrick (~> 1.8)
+    rails (7.1.3.2)
+      actioncable (= 7.1.3.2)
+      actionmailbox (= 7.1.3.2)
+      actionmailer (= 7.1.3.2)
+      actionpack (= 7.1.3.2)
+      actiontext (= 7.1.3.2)
+      actionview (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activejob (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activemodel (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activerecord (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activestorage (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
       bundler (>= 1.15.0)
-      railties (= 7.0.2.2)
+      railties (= 7.1.3.2)
     rails-controller-testing (1.0.5)
       actionpack (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
       actionview (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
       activesupport (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
-    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
-      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
+    rails-dom-testing (2.2.0)
+      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
+      minitest
       nokogiri (>= 1.6)
-    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
-      loofah (~> 2.3)
-    rails-i18n (7.0.3)
+    rails-html-sanitizer (1.6.0)
+      loofah (~> 2.21)
+      nokogiri (~> 1.14)
+    rails-i18n (7.0.9)
       i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
       railties (>= 6.0.0, < 8)
-    railties (7.0.2.2)
-      actionpack (= 7.0.2.2)
-      activesupport (= 7.0.2.2)
-      method_source
+    railties (7.1.3.2)
+      actionpack (= 7.1.3.2)
+      activesupport (= 7.1.3.2)
+      irb
+      rackup (>= 1.0.0)
       rake (>= 12.2)
-      thor (~> 1.0)
-      zeitwerk (~> 2.5)
+      thor (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.2)
+      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
     rainbow (3.1.1)
-    rake (13.0.6)
-    rb-fsevent (0.11.1)
-    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
-      ffi (~> 1.0)
-    redcarpet (3.5.1)
-    regexp_parser (2.2.1)
-    request_store (1.5.1)
+    rake (13.2.1)
+    rdoc (6.6.3.1)
+      psych (>= 4.0.0)
+    redcarpet (3.6.0)
+    reline (0.5.6)
+      io-console (~> 0.5)
+    request_store (1.7.0)
       rack (>= 1.4)
-    rexml (3.2.5)
-    rollbar (3.3.0)
-    ruby-vips (2.1.4)
+    rexml (3.2.6)
+    rollbar (3.5.2)
+    ruby-vips (2.2.1)
       ffi (~> 1.12)
-    ruby_http_client (3.5.4)
-    rubyzip (2.3.2)
+    ruby2_keywords (0.0.5)
+    ruby_http_client (3.5.5)
     sass-rails (6.0.0)
       sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
     sassc (2.4.0)
@@ -374,17 +355,12 @@ GEM
       tilt
     scrypt (3.0.7)
       ffi-compiler (>= 1.0, < 2.0)
-    selenium-webdriver (4.1.0)
-      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 5.0)
-      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
-      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
     sendgrid-actionmailer (3.2.0)
       mail (~> 2.7)
       sendgrid-ruby (~> 6.4)
-    sendgrid-ruby (6.6.1)
+    sendgrid-ruby (6.7.0)
       ruby_http_client (~> 3.4)
-    shellany (0.0.1)
-    simplecov (0.21.2)
+    simplecov (0.22.0)
       docile (~> 1.1)
       simplecov-html (~> 0.11)
       simplecov_json_formatter (~> 0.1)
@@ -393,40 +369,36 @@ GEM
     snaky_hash (2.0.1)
       hashie
       version_gem (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
-    spring (2.1.1)
-    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
-      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
-      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
-    sprockets (4.0.3)
+    sprockets (4.2.1)
       concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
-      rack (> 1, < 3)
+      rack (>= 2.2.4, < 4)
     sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
       actionpack (>= 5.2)
       activesupport (>= 5.2)
       sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
-    strip_attributes (1.12.0)
+    stringio (3.1.0)
+    strip_attributes (1.13.0)
       activemodel (>= 3.0, < 8.0)
-    strscan (3.0.1)
     style_palette (0.0.7)
     systemu (2.6.5)
     terminal-table (3.0.2)
       unicode-display_width (>= 1.1.1, < 3)
-    test-unit (3.5.3)
+    test-unit (3.6.2)
       power_assert
-    thor (1.2.1)
+    thor (1.3.1)
     thread_safe (0.3.6)
-    tilt (2.0.10)
-    timecop (0.9.5)
-    timeout (0.2.0)
+    tilt (2.3.0)
+    timecop (0.9.8)
+    timeout (0.4.1)
     turnstile-captcha (0.1.5)
       faraday
       hashie
       rails (>= 6.1.0)
-    tzinfo (2.0.4)
+    tzinfo (2.0.6)
       concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
     uglifier (4.2.0)
       execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
-    unicode-display_width (2.1.0)
+    unicode-display_width (2.5.0)
     uri (0.13.0)
     uuid (2.3.9)
       macaddr (~> 1.0)
@@ -438,21 +410,16 @@ GEM
       equalizer (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.9)
     virtus-relations (1.0.0)
       virtus (~> 1)
-    web-console (4.2.0)
+    web-console (4.2.1)
       actionview (>= 6.0.0)
       activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
       bindex (>= 0.4.0)
       railties (>= 6.0.0)
-    webdrivers (5.0.0)
-      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
-      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
-      selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0)
-    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
+    webrick (1.8.1)
+    websocket-driver (0.7.6)
       websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
     websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
-    xpath (3.2.0)
-      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
-    zeitwerk (2.5.4)
+    zeitwerk (2.6.13)
 
 PLATFORMS
   ruby
@@ -460,28 +427,23 @@ PLATFORMS
 DEPENDENCIES
   active_storage_validations
   acts-as-taggable-on
+  amazing_print
   authlogic
-  awesome_print
   aws-sdk-s3
   bluecloth
   brakeman
   bundle-audit
   byebug
-  capybara
   data_migrate
-  database_cleaner
   dotenv-rails
   factory_bot
   faker
   fast_blank
-  guard
-  guard-minitest
   i18n-tasks
   image_processing
   jbuilder
   jquery-rails
   kaminari
-  listen
   log_book
   minitest
   mocha
@@ -489,6 +451,7 @@ DEPENDENCIES
   oj
   omniauth-google-oauth2
   omniauth-rails_csrf_protection (~> 1.0)
+  prometheus-client
   puma
   rails (~> 7.0)
   rails-controller-testing
@@ -498,11 +461,8 @@ DEPENDENCIES
   ruby_regex!
   sass-rails
   scrypt
-  selenium-webdriver
   sendgrid-actionmailer
   simplecov
-  spring
-  spring-watcher-listen
   strip_attributes
   style_palette
   timecop
@@ -512,7 +472,6 @@ DEPENDENCIES
   virtus
   virtus-relations
   web-console
-  webdrivers
 
 RUBY VERSION
    ruby 3.1.1p18


The problem was that I should stop using the Controller test class: ActionController::TestCase and start using ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.
After this change, the errors disappeared.
